# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, selenium-ide, eclipse

I've added all JARS configured chromedriver.

Why this error is coming "Error: Unable to initialize main class Practice.test1
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver"
[image]

Comment: Help me dude same problem pls! provide some video tutorial how to fix this problem

Comment: Add External Jars under Class Path. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have most probably not added the proper dependencies.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61429938

I suggest looking into this response for the steps to do so with a dependency management tool, like Maven: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3167378

Comment: not able to figure out yet , installed all selenium java JARS still dont know what is missing

Comment: I suggest trying using a proper dependency manager rather than doing it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue first time, in order to solve this I checked build path configured for my project.There you will see two options 1. Module path 2. Class path

Add your all external jars such as selenium jars under class path not module path and retry. It worked for me.